# EclipseLink/MySQL/Glassfish - Table is not created, even though connection works fine

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, glassfish, eclipselink

I am trying to setup a basic JPA application that creates a simple table in mySQL.

I use glassfish 4.1, I have created connection pool/resource and pinged successfully the database from administration panel.

I created a web application project which contains just one simple entity and a persistence.xml under src/META-INF folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
 <persistence-unit name="DataPersistencePU" transaction-type="JTA">
 <jta-data-source>mysqlresource</jta-data-source>
 <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
  <properties>
  <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action"    value="create"/>
</properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And the entity file,

```
 @Entity
public class DataProvider implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof DataProvider)) {
        return false;
    }
    DataProvider other = (DataProvider) object;
    if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Entity.DataProvider[ id=" + id + " ]";
}
```

}

I also tried moving persistence.xml under /WEB-INF, still no cure.

There is no error in Glassfish logs.
I am just trying to get eclipseLink working and automatically generate the table.

Comment: Ok asking the obvious here. Did you create your `EntityManager` somewhere in your application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dark mentioned, I created EntityManager, started a transaction and persisted a row to the table:

```
@WebServlet(name = "TestUsertServlet", urlPatterns = {"/TestUsertServlet"})
@PersistenceContext(
    unitName = "DataPersistencePU")
@TransactionAttribute(REQUIRED)
 public class TestUsertServlet extends HttpServlet {

@Resource
private javax.transaction.UserTransaction utx;

@PersistenceContext
EntityManager em;

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,     HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet TestUsertServlet</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Servlet TestUsertServlet at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }
}

@Override

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try {
        utx.begin();
        TestUser testUser = new TestUser();
        em.persist(testUser);
        utx.commit();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But would like to know why EntityManager is needed in order for the table to be created.
I thought that EM has to do only with Persistence Context, the lifecycle of Entities related with the database, which means objects representing records to a table, not the table itself, right?

Comment: EclipseLink lazily deploys persistence units to avoid the overhead when many might be found on the classpath and go unused.  See https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/p_deploy_on_startup.htm#delayonstartup if you want to change it to deploy upfront.